# Node.Js error - listener must be a function

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build an endpoint /order.... where an order a POST request can be made.

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  hostname: '127.0.0.1'
  ,port: '8080'
  ,path: '/order'
  ,method: 'GET'
  ,headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
};

var s  = http.createServer(options, function(req,res) {

  res.on('data', function(){
       // Success message for receiving request. //
       console.log("We have received your request successfully.");
  });
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1'); // I understand that options object has already defined this. 

req.on('error', function(e){
  console.log("There is a problem with the request:\n" + e.message);
});

req.end();
```

I get an error "listener must be a function"....when trying to run it from command line - "node sample.js"

I want to be able to run this service and curl into it.
 Can someone proof read my code and give me some basic directions on where I am going wrong? and how I may improve my code.

Comment: If you have a new question, don't update this question. Post a new question.

Comment: `req` is a string and strings don't have `.on()` method

Comment: @Trott: The updated code is OK since the updated bug also appears in the original code. The only answer to this question when the code was updated didn't address that bug.

Comment: so how would i catch the error event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`http.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) does not take an `options` object as a parameter. Its only parameter is a listener, which must be a function, not an object.

Here's a really simple example of how it works:

```
var http = require('http');

// Create an HTTP server
var srv = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('okay');
});

srv.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: should i use 'var server = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');' instead?

Comment: `http.request()` sends a request. In other words, it's a client, not a server. So, if you are trying to create a client: yes. If you are trying to create a server: no.